# Stop slurm sbatch from copying script to compute node

Tags: slurm

Is there a way to stop sbatch from copying the script to the compute node. For example when I run:

```
sbatch --mem=300 /shared_between_all_nodes/test.sh
```

test.sh is copied to /var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd/etc/ on the executing compute node. The trouble with this is there are other scripts in /shared_between_all_nodes/ that test.sh needs to use and I would like to avoid hard coding the path.

In sge I could use qsub -b y to stop it from copying the script to the compute node. Is there a similar option or config in slurm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sbatch --wrap is a nice solution for this

```
sbatch --wrap /shared_between_all_nodes/test.sh
```

quotes are required if the script has parameters

```
sbatch --wrap "/shared_between_all_nodes/test.sh param1 param2"
```

from sbatch docs http://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

> --wrap=
>   Sbatch will wrap the specified command string in a simple "sh" shell script, and submit that script to the slurm controller. When --wrap is used, a script name and arguments may not be specified on the command line; instead the sbatch-generated wrapper script is used.

Answer (score 0):

The script might be copied there, but the working directory will be the directory in which the `sbatch` command is launched. So if the command is launched from `/shared_between_all_nodes/` it should work.

To be able to lauch `sbatch` form anywhere, use this option

```
   -D, --workdir=<directory>
          Set the working directory of the batch script to directory before 
          it is executed.
```

like

```
sbatch --mem=300 -D /shared_between_all_nodes /shared_between_all_nodes/test.sh
```

Comment: I need to be able to get the directory where the submitted script is located, rather than the working directory